# Spring Session not setting X-Auth-Token, JSESSIONID still present

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-session

I'm trying to figure out why Spring Session isn't setting the session header and is still setting the `JSESSIONID`. Also, I'm trying to determine why my test doesn't get the `JSESSIONID` that the browser does. I'm not trying to use redis, just the in memory store.

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @RequestMapping( "/" )
    public String greeting() {
        return "hello";
    }



    @Configuration
    @Order( SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER )
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        static SessionRepository<? extends ExpiringSession> repository() {
            return new MapSessionRepository( );
        }

        @Bean
        static HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
            return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
        }

        @Autowired
        void globalUserDetails( final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth ) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser( "admin" ).password( "admin" ).roles( "USER", "ADMIN" );
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.httpBasic()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication( Application.class );
        app.setShowBanner( false );
        app.run( args );
    }
}
```

and a test class

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringApplicationConfiguration( classes = { MockServletContext.class, Application.class } )
public class ApplicationTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc = null;
    private MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder;
    @Autowired private WebApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup( context )
                .addFilter( springSecurityFilterChain )
                .build();

        requestBuilder = get( "/" )
                .header( "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( "admin:admin".getBytes() ) );
    }

    @Test
    public void getSessionToken() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform( requestBuilder )
                .andExpect( status().is2xxSuccessful() )
                .andExpect( header().string( "X-Auth-Token", notNullValue() ) );
    }

    @Test
    public void getJessionId() throws Exception {
     // response does not agree with an actual browser request which has a JSESSIONID
        this.mockMvc.perform( requestBuilder )
                .andExpect( status().is2xxSuccessful() )
                .andExpect( cookie().doesNotExist( "JSESSIONID" ) );
    }
}
```

these are the response headers chrome has when I login at  `/`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6D7E2CB0AAFDD3B5DB53BA77C0725750; Path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 5
Date: Fri, 29 May 2015 01:16:33 GMT
```

and lastly here's my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xenoterracide</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-session-test-case</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

why am I not getting the `X-Auth-Token` header instead of the `JESSIONID` Cookie? and why doesn't my test say that I'm getting the `JSESSIONID` cookie?

Comment: What version of Spring Security is that pulling in?

Comment: @chrylis http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/ 3.2.7

Comment: I know default behavior changed between 3.2 and 4.0. Perhaps you need a `with().csrf()`?

Comment: You haven't configured the filter so basically nothing is happening. Add an additional bean extending `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer` which configures Spring Session. Remove the 2 beans from the other configuration.

Comment: @chrylis csrf shouldn't have anything to do with this, and I have it working in my more full version.

Comment: @M.Deinum maybe that's right? I'll check it out later, though it'd be nice to know what exactly I have to add in an answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried adding that and passing it Application and removing those beans from the config unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work, you also have to add it as a filter in your test, only adding in the context isn't enough. It isn't part of the Spring Security chain but it is a regular filter.

Comment: This is a good guide for this implementation https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-rest.html#rest-sample

Answer (score 3):

You need to add configuration class doing three things:

1. Enabling `SessionRepositoryFilter` (this is done by `@EnableSpringHttpSession` annotation)
2. Providing bean implementing `HttpSessionIdResolver` interface - in your case HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver
3. Because `@EnableSpringHttpSession` requires providing `SessionRepository` - it needs to provide a bean implementing this interface as well (`MapSessionRepository` used in example below)

Sample configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.session.MapSessionRepository;
import org.springframework.session.config.annotation.web.http.EnableSpringHttpSession;
import org.springframework.session.web.http.HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver;
import org.springframework.session.web.http.HttpSessionIdResolver;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

@Configuration
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    MapSessionRepository sessionRepository() {
        return new MapSessionRepository(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to define proper HttpSessionIdResolver implementation. By default spring-session uses CookieHttpSessionIdResolver.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.session.web.http.HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver;
import org.springframework.session.web.http.HttpSessionIdResolver;

@Configuration
public class SessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }
}
```

At least it works for Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE.